# XSLT / XML: convert apostrophe to a specific entity string

Tags: xml, xslt, character-encoding, escaping

I'd like to be able to convert an apostrophe to the string `&apos;` using XSLT. I've got the following XML

```
<OrgName>King's College</OrgName>
```

I'd like to be able to output the following:

```
<OrgName>King&apos;s College</OrgName>
```

I've tried a character map but I don't think this works as you can only replace a single character with a string.

I've also tried a replace function but I'm not sure what I can do to make sure that the full string actually appears in the output file?

```
<xsl:value-of select='replace(OrgName,"&amp;apos;","&amp;apos;")' />
```

In my final solution I need to be able to replace all apostrophe's in the text rather than just for one node.

Comment: ">I've tried a character map but I don't think this works as you can only replace a single character with a string." But replacing a character with a string is exactly what you are trying to do. Character maps can do this job, it seems you did something wrong.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution using character maps. :)

Comment: Thanks for answers, I'll check if I can get them working. The reason I didn't think a character map would work is that I thought the apostrophe would be represented by the predefined entity &apos; even though it doesn't appear like that in the file. To me "&apos;" looks like a string rather than a single character so I thought it wasn't possible. Perhaps I'm not understanding how entities work? I'm  also confused about why I'm able to use the literal ' rather than the entity string in the original XML document.

Comment: Do note that both XML documents are the same from the point of view of a real XML consumer.

Comment: @Michael Kay - You're right, I was doing something wrong. The character map was working and outputting "&apos;" Problem was I was then reparsing the output and building a JDOM document which was undoing my work. Now I'm just writing an output stream directly to a file from the transformation it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using a [*character map*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps) is as simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" use-character-maps="mApos"/>

    <xsl:character-map name="mApos">
     <xsl:output-character character="&apos;" string="&amp;apos;"/>
    </xsl:character-map>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<OrgName>King's College</OrgName>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<OrgName>King&apos;s College</OrgName>
```

Comment: @MarcoS: Yes, character maps are one of the nice new features in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: do we have same method available for xslt1.0?

Comment: @softwaredev, No, character maps were introduced first in XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer:

For replacing the character `'` you may use the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(xs:string(str), 
                              codepoints-to-string(39), 
                              '&amp;apos;')"/>
```

which requires XSLT/XPath 2.0. Explanation `codepoints-to-string` returns a string from a sequence of code points, and `39` corresponds to the character `'`'

For doing this replacement on every node of your XML ... I have no solution at the moment: will think about it.

Anyway, I hope this helps.